# Can't center a column in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I've been trying to center a div in bootstrap 4 with little luck. I could get the `offset` method to work, but it didn't work across screen sizes and the `mx-auto` didn't work either. I couldn't fine any usable help for this in the documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use the `justify-content-center` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Comment: I can see how that could make sense. I'm creating a ul > li inside a col inside a row. Where should I apply the `justify-content-center` class?